# Loop through JSON array: uncaught syntax error, uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm still new to JQuery and I'm trying to use it to iterate through a JSON array and update my webpage with the data in the array.

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "firstname":"John",
        "lastname":"Doe",
        "studentnumber":"666"
    },
    {
        "firstname":"Foo",
        "lastname":"Bar",
        "studentnumber":"777"
    }
]
```

My HTML document looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log('ready');
                $.getJSON('us.json', function(data){
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){
                       $.each(value, function(index, member){
                            html += '<div class="member">';
                            html += '<h4>' + member.firstname + ' ' + member.lastname +'</h2>';
                            html += '<p>' + 'has the following member number:' + member.studentnumber + '</p>';
                            html += '</div>';
                            console.log(html)
                        })
                    });
                    $('#members').html(html);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <h3>Members</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="members"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that I'm trying to use the `.each` function to accomplish this task. The above code is giving the following error:

```
VM2028:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
(anonymous function) @ index-v1.html:10
fire                 @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3187
self.fireWith        @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3317
done                 @ jquery-2.2.3.js:8785
(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.2.3.js:9151
```

After looking at some previous questions here, I tried replacing `JSON.parse(data)` with just `data`, and this resulted in the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined
(anonymous function) @ index-v1.html:12
jQuery.extend.each   @ jquery-2.2.3.js:371
(anonymous function) @ index-v1.html:11
jQuery.extend.each   @ jquery-2.2.3.js:365
(anonymous function) @ index-v1.html:10
fire                 @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3187
self.fireWith        @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3317
done                 @ jquery-2.2.3.js:8785
(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.2.3.js:9151
```

What could be causing these problems and how do I fix them?

Comment: "After looking at some previous questions here, I tried replacing JSON.parse(data) with just data" — Err… so you've fixed the problem in your question title already…

Comment: @Quentin You're right, the title is poorly worded. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause of error: ***`JSON.parse()` expects a text but object is passed.***(Thanks to @[Rayon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746830/rayon))

As `data` is already in JSON format, there is no need of using `JSON.parse()` on it.

```
$.getJSON('us.json', function(data){

    // Problem is here
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
```

**Don't parse `data`**

```
$.getJSON('us.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
```

For second error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined

Define `html` variable before using it.

```
var html = ''; // Add before `each`.
```

---

Also, there is no need of nested `each` as the data passed in first `each` is already `member` object. Here's code written using `Array#forEach`.

```
$.getJSON('us.json', function (data) {
    var html = '';
    data.forEach(function(member) {
        html += '<div class="member">';
        html += '<h4>' + member.firstname + ' ' + member.lastname + '</h2>';
        html += '<p>' + 'has the following member number:' + member.studentnumber + '</p>';
        html += '</div>';
    });

    $('#members').html(html);
});
```

Comment: Cause of error: _`JSON.parse` expects a `text` but `object` is passed.._

Comment: @Rayon Thanks. Added.

Comment: This has fixed the errors that were occurring, thank you. However it seems your code skips over the first object in the JSON array. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @PythonNewb Can't say from here, can you check if there is any error in browser console? Also check in ELEMENTS tab if the first item is hidden or misplaced.

Comment: @Tushar There are no errors and it doesn't seem like any elements are hidden. However I added a `console.log()` statement and found that both objects were logged to the console. Could it be because the first element is overwritten by the second one? They both have the same html class.

Comment: "already return data in JSON format. There is no need of converting it to JSON " — No. It gets JSON and then it parses it into JavaScript objects/arrays/strings/etc. Parsing JSON doesn't turn something into JSON, it does the opposite of that.